# Is there any maximum numbers of Gems that a Team can Buy?

Tags: dota-2

I've heard, several times, that a certain team in Dota 2, can't buy more than `X` gems (where `X` varies from 2 to 4) and thats why some people don't break the gems of the other team once they drop them, keeping them safe at the base.

Is this true or it's just a Myth ? Whats the maximum number of Gems a team can buy ?

I know gems have a `restock time` but i'm not sure if there's a limit to the number of gem instances per team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***A team can buy as many gem as they wish.***

That being said, as you pointed out: [The Gem](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Gem_of_True_Sight) does have a 10 minutes restock timer and only a single Gem can be in stock at any given time.

So technically, the maximum amount of gems a team can buy is equal to the total game timer dived by 10, rounded up. :)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Rounded up. You can buy the first one almost immediately if you really wanted to.

Comment: Indeed! inb4 fast gem builds.

Comment: if it wasn't obvious, a ten minute restock timer _for the team buying it_, not both teams